# Should apache still be making error_log files?

Tags: apache

I have a VirtualHost set up like this

```
<VirtualHost my.ip.address.here:80>
   DocumentRoot /home/todieama/public_html/dev/hop/public_html/
   ServerName dev.example.com
   ServerAlias dev.example.com
   ErrorLog /home/todieama/public_html/dev/hop/public_html/application/logs/apache.log
   ServerAdmin some@example.com
   UserDir enabled todieama
   <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
     suPHP_UserGroup todieama todieama
   </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

When a PHP error is caught, it gets logged in the apache.log file defined above, and also in error_log in dev/hop/public_html. Should it still be logging here? I'd like to stop if it's possible.

Comment: you may ask this question at: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't think _dev/hop/public_html/error_log_ will be logging any as it is not mentioned in the vHost...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure these log files are not symlinked? Do they has equal size?